# Draw.io open link in new window

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to have a link in my chart that I created with draw.io open in a new window.  It is currently opening in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

You can change what happens when you click on a link in a diagram so that it opens in a new tab or the same tab in draw.io for Confluence Server.

https://drawio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000074290-change-how-diagram-links-open-on-confluence-server